# Get capture parameter in request

Tags: django

I have a url defined like:

```
url(r'^path/(?P<person>\w+)/$', views.Something.as_view()),
```

Can I access that `person` parameter from within request object? Is there something like `request.resolved_path.capture_groups['person']`?

Comment: Why do you need to access it "within the request object"? It's passed to your view, you should access it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is in the kwargs of your view so e.g. for a form view :

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    person = self.kwargs.get('person', None)
```

Will get yout the person from the url.

Answer (score 0):

You can access this person variable in your view like this.

```
def my_view(request, person):
    print(person)
    # Do whatever with this person object.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: He is using a Class based view `views.Something.as_view()`